# Whats going on with MVC5+ Assemblies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, nuget, asp.net-mvc-5

I was planning to upgrade my project from MVC 4 to MVC5.  I followed this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2.  I did all the steps successfully, but got errors that the 5.0 dll could not be loaded.

The article, however, has no mention of where to get the DLLs.  So I started looking for the DLLs everywhere, my file system, online, Google, etc.

Then I created my own MVC5 test project and noticed that the MVC 5.1 DLLs got added from nuget.

So, is Microsoft only distributing MVC dlls from nuget?
Also, I can find the MVC4 dlls from the file system and MVC5.1 dlls from the nuget package, where are the MVC5.0 dlls?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific version from NuGet, open the Package Manager Console and type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.1
```

Which is the latest in the 5.0 series.